# Error when specifying the directionality of a claim for a d-separation test [piecewiseSEM + glmmTMB paths]. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: r, piecewise, glmmtmb, structural-equation-model

I'm trying to run a SEM analysis with count data.
I'm using `piecewiseSEM` package (2.30) with paths fit via `glmmTMB` (1.1.8-9000).

Based on previous tests, the fit of `piecewiseSEM` models using `glmmTMB` paths is performing ok.
However, there is a possible directionality conflict in the basis set of one model.
This situation is not really an issue and the solutions are well documented by the package author.
(see: [text](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/local-estimation.html#tests-of-directed-separation))

However, the problem emerges when the solutions (which works for other packages) don't seem to work for `glmmTMB`.

I managed to make a minimal reproducible example using the following code:

```
require(piecewiseSEM)
require(glmmTMB)

simData = data.frame(sp1 = runif(300),
                     sp2 = rpois(300, 3),
                     sp3 = rpois(300, 5),
                     sp4 = rpois(300, 1))

# Model structure:

#      sp2
#sp1 <     > sp4
#      sp3
    
SEM <- psem( 
  glmmTMB(sp2 ~ sp1, family = poisson, data = simData),
  glmmTMB(sp3 ~ sp1, family = poisson, data = simData),
  glmmTMB(sp4 ~ sp2 + sp3, family = poisson, data = simData),
  data = simData)

basisSet(SEM)

summary(SEM) #The conflict is shown here

summary(SEM, direction = c("sp3 <- sp2")) #The error happens here
```

The summary retuns the following error message:

> n str2lang(x) : :2:0: unexpected end of input
> 1: . ~  sp3 + sp2 + sp1  +
> ^

I tried the same test while fitting the paths with other packages (`glmer` and `glm`) and it works.
The problem seems to be limited to `glmmTMB` (I didn't tested all supported packages though).

I also tried a few package versions (`piecewiseSEM` and `glmmTMB`), and a few R versions. But they were the same.

Since I really need to use `glmmTMB` for my analysis does anyone know whether is this a bug of am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Recording how far I've gotten in my archaeology:

Using `traceback()`/`options(error = recover)`, we can see that the error happens within `piecewiseSEM:::testBasisSetElements`. This code extracted and modified reproduces the error:

```r
bMod <- glmmTMB(sp4 ~ sp2 + sp3, family = poisson, data = simData)
bnew <- paste0("sp", 1:3)
bNewMod <- suppressWarnings(update(bMod, formula(paste(". ~ ", 
            paste(rev(bnew), collapse = " + "), " + ", 
            piecewiseSEM:::onlyBars(formula(bMod)))), 
            data = simData))
```

`onlyBars(...)` returns a blank string, which makes me guess that the problem here is that `piecewiseSEM` **assumes that models will include**/**only works with models that include** at least one random effect.

Comment: Hi. Indeed, it seems to have solved the problem. Thank you very much.